# Snowflake Regex - extract string between delimiter

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, extract

Need help in getting desired output in snowflake using RegEx. Text after'-' and up to ';'

Input string '008-1994; 023-1905; 030-2330'
Desired result  1994;1905;2330

Ex2

Input string '008-XXX; 023-YYY; 030-ZZZ ; 042-AAA'
Desired result  XXX; YYY; ZZZ; AAA

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is using regex your main requirement? It can be easier to extract what you need using the split_part function

Comment: split_part would be complicated with this, because it's actually an array of values that need to be split.  You'd need to do a lateral flatten, split_part, and then a listagg to accomplish, I think.

Comment: I am ok to use split_part @aek

Answer (score 1):

This is the version using a `SPLIT`

```
--input string
set str = '008-1994; 023-1905; 030-2330';

select listagg(split_part(C.value::string, '-', 2)) from LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>split($str, ' ')) as c;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I would have split on `;` and then listagg'ed it back in, but this is what I had in mind in my comment.  Well done!

Answer (score 0):

```
SET STR= '008-1994; 023-1905; 030-2330';

SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR($STR,'\\d+-(\\d+);\\s',1,1,'e',1) AS FIRST
,REGEXP_SUBSTR($STR,'\\d+-(\\d+);\\s',1,2,'e',1) AS SECOND
,REGEXP_SUBSTR($STR,'\\d+-(\\d+)',1,3,'e',1) AS THIRD;
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/34447179)